# How is possible to loop through rows creating ranges and loop inside of this ranges and start over when the value changes

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I'm trying to loop through some rows in Excel to gather info and paste it in other sheet. Basically I need to loop through rows and specify ranges based on the product name so when the next row has a new product name the range starts over. This will gather all the attributes for the same product and be able to insert the attributes separated by coma only in the first row of the new range/new sheet and then will copy the variations from the given file.

I can copy all the variations from the original sheet to the new sheet but the first row should have all the attributes (size/color) in one cell. I managed to follow some code that i found here but I only get the arrays of the attributes and create the variations. The parent product should be created from this range of info.

```
Sub ProductVariations()

Dim productRow As Long, variationRow As Long
Dim size As String
Dim color As String
Dim skuCounter As Integer
Dim skuChild As String
Dim sizeArray() As String
Dim colorArray() As String
Dim sizeElement As Variant
Dim colorElement As Variant
Dim productsSheet As Worksheet
Dim variationsSheet As Worksheet

productRow = 2
variationRow = 2

Set productsSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Set variationSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2)

'loop through each row until a blank row is found
While productsSheet.Cells(productRow, 1).Value <> ""

   'get the size and color values for the current row
   size = productsSheet.Cells(productRow, 3)
   color = productsSheet.Cells(productRow, 4)

   'make sure a size and color exists then process
   If Len(size) > 0 And Len(color) > 0 Then

       'reset the sku counter
       skuCounter = 0

       'split the size and color into arrays
       sizeArray = Split(size, "|")
       colorArray = Split(color, "|")

       'loop through each size
       For Each sizeElement In sizeArray

           'loop through each color
           For Each colorElement In colorArray

               'increment the child counter for this variation
               skuCounter = skuCounter + 1

               'set the appropriate cells in the variations sheet (you have some more work to do here
               skuChild = productsSheet.Cells(productRow, 2).Value & "-" & skuCounter

               variationSheet.Cells(variationRow, 1).Value = productsSheet.Cells(productRow, 1)
               variationSheet.Cells(variationRow, 3).Value = skuChild

               'increment the variation row so the next variation goes in the next row
               variationRow = variationRow + 1

           Next colorElement

       Next sizeElement

   End If

   'very important increment the next row or only the first row will ever get processed
   productRow = productRow + 1
Wend 
End Sub
```

Any help  is appreciated. Thanks